# mysql full-text match parenthesis grouping not working

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have a full text query that has a value when there is no grouping:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS cnt FROM wp_product wp WHERE
(MATCH(wp.longtitle,wp.artist,wp.catNo,wp.apn) AGAINST('+something
+for +kate ' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ) AND wp.onlines = 1;
```

This returns 1192.

But when I try to add a grouping using parenthesis, no record is returned.

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS cnt FROM wp_product wp WHERE
(MATCH(wp.longtitle,wp.artist,wp.catNo,wp.apn) AGAINST('+(something somethin)
+for +kate ' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ) AND wp.onlines = 1;
```

This returns 0.

From what I know, if there is no + operator inside a parenthesis it should be "OR" right? so why does the second query return 0?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, this was because "something" is a stopword. After removing stopword list, this was resolved.